# React Native Bottom Sheet not reacting for touch input

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-gesture-handler, react-native-reanimated-v2

I would like to use [React Native Bottom Sheet](https://github.com/gorhom/react-native-bottom-sheet) in my new expo app (`expo init`).

I've followed the instructions [here](https://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet/).
Check out the GitHub Repo [here](https://github.com/Knaackee/react-native-bottom-sheet-expo-problem).

Here is what i did.

1. `expo init` (blank typescript project)
2. `yarn add @gorhom/bottom-sheet@^4`
3. `yarn add react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler`
4. Replacing the content of the `App.tsx` with [snippet from the docs](https://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet/usage).
5. Added `react-native-reanimated/plugin` to babel.

   ```
    module.exports = function (api) {
      api.cache(true);
      return {
        presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
        plugins: ["react-native-reanimated/plugin"],
      };
    };
   ```
6. Started expo using `expo start --clear`

### The Bottom Sheet is visible but is not reacting to touch input (not moving). It reacts to code changes (changing snap points etc.). I use the android emulator, but I've tried it on my phone too.

[Here is a GitHub Repo showing the problem](https://github.com/Knaackee/react-native-bottom-sheet-expo-problem)

Comment: you have used basic example which is non-scrollable..  please check this link for scrollable bottom-sheet (https://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet/components/bottomsheetview(

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your entire Layout in **GestureHandlerRootView** if your using Android.

**Import:**

```js
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
```

**Layout:**

```js
<GestureHandlerRootView style={{flex: 1}}>
// Your layout
</GestureHandlerRootView>
```

[Similar problem has already been solved here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71618989/react-native-gesture-handler-not-working-on-android)